# Sleep or Stopwatch Not Measuring Accurately

Tags: .net, powershell, timer, stopwatch

I need to check how long it takes a couple of scripts to run, and wanted to make sure I knew how to use the timer, so I wrote the short test below to check my logic:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt 11; $i++) {
    $sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000
    $sw.Stop()

    $elapsed =  $sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds
    Write-Host $elapsed
}
```

Where I am simply starting a timer, calling `Start-Sleep` for 2000 milliseconds and then outputting (what I thought would be) the elapsed time (in milliseconds).

This is the output:

```
1
6
11
11
12
9
11
12
12
11
8
```

I was not 100% sure what to expect from the output, but my assumption was that each line would be just over 2000, as this is the length of the Sleep.

Does anyone know what is going on here? I have also tested this with the other denominations (minutes, hours, seconds) with similarly confusing results.

Each time I run this script the results are different, and I can't seem to make out any pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with Stopwatch. [TimeSpan.Miliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.milliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the milisecond *component* of a TimeSpan. You should use the [TimeSpan.TotalMiliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) property to retrieve the number of elapsed miliseconds.

The most accurate value though is [TimeSpan.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx). A Stopwatch doesn't count time by itself, it reads the value in ticks of the system's high-resolution timer when it starts and stops. The Ticks property contains that difference.

You can retrieve the same values from the Stopwatch itself, eg. [Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks(v=vs.110).aspx), [Stopwatch.ElapseMiliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.heyscriptingguy.aspx).

`$sw.elapsed.milliseconds` will show **only** the milliseconds that have elapsed (leaving out the minutes and seconds)

What I need to use is `$sw.elapsedmilliseconds`